# SharePoint 2010 Vaiations site managing translations

Tags: variations, resource-files

How to manage the variations sites translations for the words? We have the English and Arabic publishing sites and we need to have the common keyowrds translations manageable easly in SharePoint 2010 or manage through the Visual Studio Solutions?

I heards using the resources files, but I am not sure how flexible and easy to manage it through the Visual Studio solution, is ther any alternate solutions handling from SharePoint using lists?